# Django checking if an individual field has an error and not run clean()?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to check if an inidividual field has not passed validation in django's `clean()` method for a form.

I don't want to have to manually be checking if a required field is there:

```
def clean():
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    half_day = cleaned_data.get('half_day')
    start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
    end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')

    if start_date and end_date:
        if half_day:
            if start_date != end_date:
                self.add_error(
                    'half_day',
                    'Start and end date must be the same'    
                )
```

Comment: You code above looks fine. It's the standard approach from the [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Comment: `assert myform.is_valid() == true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `start_date` and `end_date` are declared as `blank=False, null=False` (the default) then you can do something like this:

```
    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super(MyModelForm, self).clean()

        if not self.is_valid():
            return cleaned_data

        if cleaned_data.get('half_day'):
            if cleaned_data['start_date'] != cleaned_data['end_date']:
                self.add_error(
                    'half_day',
                    'Start and end date must be the same'    
                )

        return cleaned_data
```

The super clean will `return` the request back to the template with `errors` and you won't have to deal with checking whether the fields have values.

Comment: Note: I'm not using 2.0 yet. I see the super call could be less verbose :)

Comment: Yeah that is a new feature of python `3.6`

Comment: Cool! So can you accept this answer, or is there more to it?